# Skins not showing in game in Minecraft 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried all kinds of things to fix my skin problem but none of them show up no matter what I try. I'm using the newest update which is 1.11 so my skins should show up. Do I have to have a certain skin that is up to date with my game?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the skin servers go down for maintenance. If they are down, no skins will render on anyone's game. You can check the status of the servers [here](https://help.mojang.com/).